# yeoman webapp subfolder wrong css path

Tags: html, css, web-applications, gruntjs, yeoman

I'm using yeoman webapp generator (0.5.0) and my app dir look like:

```
app/
├── dir1
│   └── index.html
├── favicon.ico
├── images
├── index.html
├── robots.txt
├── scripts
│   └── main.js
└── styles
    └── main.css
```

In `dir1/index.html` i've just copied the content of `app/index.html` and modified the path of css and js files.
For example from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
```

Using `grunt serve` everything works, but when i build with `grunt build` the paths in `dir1/index.html` are wrong. From the chrome developer console i can see some errors:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/webapp/dir1/styles/9c307a9d.vendor.css        127.0.0.1/:1
GET http://127.0.0.1/webapp/dir1/styles/84f823a4.main.css          127.0.0.1/:1
GET http://127.0.0.1/webapp/dir1/scripts/db02b173.vendor.js           (index):3
GET http://127.0.0.1/webapp/dir1/scripts/cb7562c6.plugins.js          (index):8
GET http://127.0.0.1/webapp/dir1/scripts/b6c3df09.main.js             (index):8
```

The right paths should be:

```
http://127.0.0.1/webapp/styles/9c307a9d.vendor.css
http://127.0.0.1/webapp/styles/84f823a4.main.css
http://127.0.0.1/webapp/scripts/db02b173.vendor.js
http://127.0.0.1/webapp/scripts/cb7562c6.plugins.js
http://127.0.0.1/webapp/scripts/b6c3df09.main.js
```

The problem is that some grunt task uses `dir1` as root dir instead of the parent directory.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found how to fix this!
In `dir1/index.html` i had to change not only the relative path of external files (css, js) but also but also the grunt block, for example the code:

```html
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

should be modified as:

```html
<!-- build:css(.) ../styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) ../styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Change to site relative rather than path relative

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't solve my problem. After running `grunt build` the paths became again relative